# How to manage User Scope using Koin?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I'm trying to create a user scope using Koin.
When the user is logged, I'm creating the scope :

```
val scope = getKoin().createScope("USER_SCOPE")
```

And when the user clicks on logout, I'm destroying the scope

```
    scope?.let {userScope ->
        userScope.close()
        getKoin().deleteScope(userScope.id)
    }
```

In my koin module, I have a `scoped` UserRepository which should live only during the user session. I also have ViewModels and Use Cases which are using this repository, and I try to inject the `scoped` repo inside them

```
val appModule = module {
    scoped<UserRepository> { UserDataRepository() }
    viewModel { UserViewModel(getScope("USER_SCOPE").get()) }
    factory { MyUseCase(getScope("USER_SCOPE").get()) }
}
```

On the first login, it is working normally, I have my user repo injected in my viewmodel and use case. But after a logout (which is deleting the scope) and after another login, the UserRepository instance is still exactly the same.

Do I miss something in the scope usage ?

Comment: Are you sure that `scope` is not null and the `let` block is called?

Comment: Yes `scope` var is not null and it is going inside the `let` block

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Migrating from koin `2.0.0-rc-2` to koin `2.0.0-GA` solved my problem.

After migrating, it is not possible to declare a `scoped` instance outside a `scope`. So I adapted my `appmodule` this way :

```
   val appModule = module {
        scope(named("USER_SCOPE")) {
            scoped<UserRepository> { UserDataRepository() }
        }
        viewModel { UserViewModel(getScope("USER_SCOPE").get()) }
        factory { MyUseCase(getScope("USER_SCOPE").get()) }
    }
```

Scope declaration is also a bit different :

```
val scope = getKoin().createScope("USER_SCOPE", named("USER_SCOPE"))
```

This way I have my `UserRepository` recreated after a logout/login.

Comment: You still need to delete the scope on the logout right? (I'm trying to do the same :P)

Comment: do you have a more complete example of how you achieve this? I am trying something similar.